# WHERE CASE WHEN statement with Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am creating a SQL query having `WHERE CASE WHEN` statement. I am doing something wrong and getting error.

My SQL statement is like

```
DECLARE @AreaId INT = 2
DECLARE @Areas Table(AreaId int)

INSERT INTO @Areas SELECT AreaId
FROM AreaMaster
WHERE CityZoneId IN (SELECT CityZoneId FROM AreaMaster WHERE AreaId = @AreaID)

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.CompanyMaster
WHERE AreaId IN
     (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT BusinessId
                        FROM dbo.AreaSubscription
                        WHERE AreaSubscription.BusinessId = CompanyMaster.BusinessId) 
             THEN @AreaId 
             ELSE (SELECT [@Areas].AreaId FROM @Areas)
      END)
```

I am getting error as

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery
>   follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an
>   expression.

Please help to successfully run query. My logic is to checking for conditional `AreaId` in (statement) for each row.

I want to select the row only when

1. company has subscription entry into `AreaSubscription` for specific area passed by `@AreaId`
2. table `AreaSubscription` does not have subscription entry then evaluate `AreaId` in `(SELECT [@Areas].AreaId FROM @Areas)`

Comment: `SELECT [@Areas].AreaId FROM @Areas` is this return multiple values?

Comment: Yes it return the list of areas which I have created before in query.

Comment: i think the subquery exception is there. What about the result of `(SELECT BusinessId
    FROM dbo.AreaSubscription
    WHERE AreaSubscription.BusinessId = CompanyMaster.BusinessId) ` ? multiple?

Comment: I am using WHEN EXISTS with that sub query, so i think there is no error in that statement. If one or more row exists then it just rerun true.

Comment: CASE WHEN what EXISTS?

Comment: i tried this in my server it worked...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This may help you.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.CompanyMaster
WHERE AreaId=
(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT BusinessId
                   FROM dbo.AreaSubscription
                   WHERE AreaSubscription.BusinessId = CompanyMaster.BusinessId) 
      THEN @AreaId ELSE AreaId END)
AND  AreaId IN (SELECT [@Areas].AreaId FROM @Areas)
```

One more solution is

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.CompanyMaster A 
LEFT JOIN @Areas B ON A.AreaId=B.AreaID
WHERE A.AreaId=
(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT BusinessId
                   FROM dbo.AreaSubscription
                   WHERE AreaSubscription.BusinessId = CompanyMaster.BusinessId) 
      THEN @AreaId ELSE B.AreaId END)
)
```

Comment: first solution work for me, Thanks. I have another solution too...Which is I have used table value function and separate the logic of where clause and instead of that logic I have used function.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting SELECT top 1 [@Areas].AreaId FROM @Areas if it solves the issue..

Comment: I need to check AreaId in (all areas), So I can't put top 1 to that statement too....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @AreaId INT = 2
DECLARE @Areas Table(AreaId int)

INSERT INTO @Areas 
SELECT AreaId FROM AreaMaster
WHERE CityZoneId IN (SELECT CityZoneId FROM AreaMaster WHERE AreaId = @AreaID)

    IF EXISTS (SELECT BusinessId
        FROM dbo.AreaSubscription
        WHERE AreaSubscription.BusinessId = CompanyMaster.BusinessId) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM dbo.CompanyMaster
        WHERE AreaId IN (@AreaId) 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM dbo.CompanyMaster
        WHERE AreaId IN (SELECT [@Areas].AreaId FROM @Areas)
    END
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, Please read question carefully.

Comment: @Haresh - put your query and some test data in your question so that people can test it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @AreaId INT = 2
DECLARE @Areas Table(AreaId int)

INSERT INTO @Areas SELECT AreaId
FROM AreaMaster
WHERE CityZoneId IN (SELECT CityZoneId FROM AreaMaster WHERE AreaId = @AreaID)

INSERT INTO @Areas 
SELECT AreaSubscription.BusinessId
    FROM dbo.AreaSubscription INNER join CompanyMaster
    ON AreaSubscription.BusinessId = CompanyMaster.BusinessId   

SELECT * FROM dbo.CompanyMaster
WHERE AreaId IN (SELECT DISTINCT [@Areas].AreaId FROM @Areas)
```